# Show some number of identical div on submit button

Tags: jquery, jsp

There is a dropdown list of values and a submit button. Based on the value selected from the dropdown list, I want to create that many identical divs and show it on the page. How to do it?

Comment: i first tried to create a fixed number of divs(say 4), and display it on click of button, but it gets displayed for few seconds and then the page refreshes

Comment: edit your question by adding some code please take a survey of how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that clear what you are asking. but I tried what I understand based on your question and comment.

```js
$('#btn').click(function(e){
  
  var data = $('#data').val();
  var txtVal = $('#txt').val();
  var html = "";
  if(data){
    for(var i=0; i < data; i++){
      html += '<div>'+txtVal+'</div>';
    }
  }
  $('#cont').html(html);
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="data">
  <option value=""> --select</option>
  <option value="1"> 1</option>
  <option value="2"> 2</option>
  <option value="3"> 3</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="submit" value="click" id="btn"/>
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Comment: the dropdown list has values from 1 to 10..based on the value selected from dropdown, i want to create that many identical divs(having a text input and a submit button) and display it on the page